# MariaDB (mysql like) How to get the index value of a selected row in a sql table? This the unique index, not a row count

Tags: mysql, sql

Say you have a table...  Index is primary key...

```
Index Sensor
1     BME280
2     BMP280
```

And want to return the Index value only of a matching select query?

SELECT * FROM Sensor WHERE Sensor = 'BME280' Will return...

```
Index Sensor
1     BME280
```

But if I only want the index?

I could have sworn in the past I could use ROWid or INDEX() or such?  But now having not done SQL work for a while, I can seem to get only the index returned for the matching row?  What am I forgetting?

Adding example of what I am seeing...

[image]

When I try just getting INDEX...

[image]

Error message...

[image]

I am using HeidiSQL as a front end, never had an issue with it, and this so simple a query it is really driving me nuts, why I cannot get INDEX when * works, even trying INDEX,Sensor generates and error when the table only has the auto-increment index and one column, 'Sensor' right now.

I dropped the WHERE clause for the example, but still SELECT INDEX FROM Sensor Where (Sensor = 'BME280'); Should as I understand it just return the Index of 1 because BME280 is in the first record in table with an index of 1 (See the first example).

Comment: Are you looking for `SELECT Index FROM Sensor WHERE...` ?

Comment: I tried just Index, reports error...  Which seems odd so why I asked if something changed with MariaDB/mysql query methods.

Comment: Which was the error ?

Comment: Just added see above.

Comment: As work-around in my (python) code, I just do an extra SELECT query using *, strip out the index value for use later in a INTO (update) query to a different part of the script, minor impact because the table is only 2 columns, but later will have much larger dataset so trying to understand what the issue is.